Unable to connect to azure function "Invalid connection string format. Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')"
I am new to azure functions and I am writing a program to write a file to an azure storage account. This is my
local.setting.json
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "ConnectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=[http|https];AccountName=<accountName>;AccountKey=<accountKey>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
  }
}

FileUpload.cs
namespace FileUpload
{
    public  class FileUpload
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString;

        public  FileUpload(string connectionString)
        {
           _connectionString = connectionString;
        }

        [FunctionName("FileUpload")]
        public  async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            try {
                Console.WriteLine("Connection String", _connectionString);

                string Connection = _connectionString;

                string shareName = "my-share";
                string dirName = req.Query["dirName"];

                var files = req.Form.Files["File"];

                ShareClient share = new(Connection, shareName);
                ShareDirectoryClient directory = share.GetDirectoryClient(dirName);

                if (!directory.Exists())
                {
                    directory.Create();
                }

                ShareFileClient file = directory.GetFileClient(files.FileName);

                using (Stream stream = files.OpenReadStream())
                {
                    await file.CreateAsync(stream.Length);
                    await file.UploadAsync(stream);
                }

                string responseMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("File uploaded successfully");

                return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                string responseMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex);

                return new BadRequestObjectResult(responseMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}

and this is
Startup.cs
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(FileUpload.Startup))]

namespace FileUpload
{
    class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionString");

            FileUpload file = new(connectionString);

            Console.WriteLine( "Connection String : "+ connectionString);


        }
    }
}

I can see that it is getting the value of connection string but not able to connect the azure share.
It throws
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration: Invalid connection string format.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

and when I tweak the code it throws
An unhandled host error has occurred.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'FileUpload.FileUpload'

am I missing DI here ? if yes how can I properly do that?


Invalid connection string format.

The above error indicates that misconfiguration of azure storage connection string. connection string set properly in the configuration might be fixed the issue.
Below code worked fine.
I have created the http trigger isolated function with run time stack C# in visual studio.
FIleUpload code:
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger, IConfiguration config)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _config = config;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            try
            {
                var formCollection = await req.ReadFormAsync();
                var file = formCollection.Files["file"];

                if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
                {
                    var connectionString = _config["AzureWebJobsStorage2"];
                    var containerName = "pavan";
                    var blobName = file.FileName;

                    var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
                    var blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
                    var blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

                    using (var fileStream = file.OpenReadStream())
                    {
                        await blobClient.UploadAsync(fileStream, true);
                    }

                    return new OkObjectResult($"File {blobName} uploaded successfully.");
                }
                else
                {
                    return new BadRequestObjectResult("Please provide a file to upload.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Error uploading file: {ex.Message}");
                return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }
    }

Program.cs:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

local.settings.json:
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage2": "your-storage conn-string"
  }
}

The above code ran successfully and successfully uploaded the code into storage container.


Output:


I want to run it from Startup.cs file so that it reads the connection string from Environment Variables or vault. In above cod will run without Program.cs directly calling Function1.

Can you show me how can we read from Environment variable or azure vault

I have updated the function code like to read conn-string from environment variable.
